# Counting number of data swaps in Java bubble sort

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to count and output the number of swaps of data elements in a bubble sort method using Java. I'm a beginner, so am unsure how to overcome my issue: method is void and can't return anything, so what can I do to output the swaps?

in one doc, the sort method:

```
public class SearchSortAlgorithms<T> implements SearchSortADT<T>
{
   //Bubble sort algorithm.
   //Postcondition: list objects are in ascending order.
    public void bubbleSort(T list[], int length)
    {
        //Initialize swap counter
        int bubbleSwaps = 0;
        for (int iteration = 1; iteration < length; iteration++)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < length - iteration;
                         index++)
            {
                Comparable<T> compElem =
                       (Comparable<T>) list[index];


                if (compElem.compareTo(list[index + 1]) > 0)
                {
                    T temp = list[index];
                    list[index] = list[index + 1];
                    list[index + 1] = temp;
                    bubbleSwaps++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In another, I use the method, and am looking to find a way to output bubbleSwaps:

```
public class numberSwapsReview{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    { 
        // define an Integer array of 1000 elements
        Integer[] bubbleArray = new Integer[1000];

        // load the array with random numbers using
        // a for loop and Math.random() method - (int)(Math.random()*1000)
        for (int i = 0; i < bubbleArray.length; i++) {
            bubbleArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
        }

        SearchSortAlgorithms<Integer> sortObject = new SearchSortAlgorithms<Integer>();

        sortObject.bubbleSort(bubbleArray, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have `bubbleSort` return `bubbleSwaps` which would allow the caller to print out this number.

Comment: i wanted to originally try that, but since I didn't want to modify the type void I was looking for another solution. How come this question is down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are making an instance of the class, you could make `bubbleSwaps` class level then get the value after the sort

```
public class SearchSortAlgorithms<T> implements SearchSortADT<T>
{
   //Initialize swap counter
   int bubbleSwaps = 0;

   //Bubble sort algorithm.
   //Postcondition: list objects are in ascending order.
    public void bubbleSort(T list[], int length)
    {

        for (int iteration = 1; iteration < length; iteration++)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < length - iteration;
                         index++)
            {
                Comparable<T> compElem =
                       (Comparable<T>) list[index];


                if (compElem.compareTo(list[index + 1]) > 0)
                {
                    T temp = list[index];
                    list[index] = list[index + 1];
                    list[index + 1] = temp;
                    this.bubbleSwaps++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

public int getBubbleSwaps(){
     return this.bubbleSwaps;
}
}
```

Here is the other class:

```
public class numberSwapsReview{
        public static void main(String [] args)
        { 
            // define an Integer array of 1000 elements
            Integer[] bubbleArray = new Integer[1000];

            // load the array with random numbers using
            // a for loop and Math.random() method - (int)(Math.random()*1000)
            for (int i = 0; i < bubbleArray.length; i++) {
                bubbleArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
            }

            SearchSortAlgorithms<Integer> sortObject = new SearchSortAlgorithms<Integer>();

            sortObject.bubbleSort(bubbleArray, 1000);
            sortObject.getBubbleSwaps();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this answer can be improved by optimizing the algorithm for when the input array is already sorted

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to change the return type of your method as `int` and return the number of swaps you did. Then just call:

```
int nbswaps = sortObject.bubbleSort(bubbleArray, 1000);
```

If you can't modify the return type, you can

- print the number of swaps in the method at the end
- create an attribute named `nbSwaps` in your class (don't forget to reset it at each call of `bubbleSort` method) and then implement a getter to be able to get the value from your main

Also you may change the declaration of your class as `class SearchSortAlgorithms<T extends Comparable<T>>`.

Now you will be sure that the elements have to be comparable and you could get rid of  `Comparable<T> compElem = (Comparable<T>) list[index];`.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a `Comparator` instead of `Comparable` elements. With that (preferable as a wrapper around the normal comparator), you can compute in a field variable how many time was the result `>0`